# Symfony 3.2 - Security Component - and another forms

Tags: php, symfony, security

I created login form like this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

But I want to create another forms in this controller: reset password and register

But submit works only on login, but submit from reset form doesn't submitted

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/login",name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{          
    $Session = $this->get('session');

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    $rememberPassword = $this->createForm(RememberPasswordType::class, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('login'),
        ));

    $rememberPassword->handleRequest($request);


    if($request->isMethod('POST')){


        if ($rememberPassword->isSubmitted() && $rememberPassword->isValid()) {

            try {

                $userEmail = $rememberPassword->get('email')->getData();

                $userManager = $this->get('user_manager');

                $userManager->sendResetPasswordLink($userEmail);

                $Session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Zostało wysłane!');

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('login'));

            } catch (UserException $exc) {
                $error = new FormError($exc->getMessage());
                $rememberPassword->get('email')->addError($error);
            }

        }
    }

    return $this->render('UserBundle:Login:login.html.twig', array(
    'last_username' => $lastUsername,
    'error'         => $error,
    'rememberPassword' => $rememberPassword->createView()
     ));
}
```

Form Type:

```
class RememberPasswordType extends AbstractType
{   

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
                        'label' => 'Email',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            new Assert\NotBlank(),
                            new Assert\Email()
                        )
                 ))
                 ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                        'label' => 'Przypomnij hasło'
                 ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'rememberPassword';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat the form separately.

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

$form1->handleRequest($request);
$form2->handleRequest($request);

if ($form1->isSubmitted()) {
    // Handle $form1
} else if ($form2->isSubmitted()) {
    // Handle $form2
}
}
```